# RRO package in OEM partition

Tags: android, android-source, rro

My rro package when I put it in system or vendor partition it works, but when I moved it in OEM partition the package is listed with `cmd overlay list`  but with an error NO_IDMAP.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot!

What I got when package is in vendor or system
`$ cmd overlay list
com.xxx.x.partnerinterface
[x] com.xxx.x.partnerinterface.rro

The output when my package is in OEM partition
com.xxx.x.partnerinterface
--- com.xxx.x.partnerinterface.rro

Answer (score 1):

I've also only used vendor and system overlays myself, but here are some various ideas:

- In the overlay Android.mk did you setup the overlay using `LOCAL_OEM_MODULE` instead of `LOCAL_VENDOR_MODULE` like so:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_OEM_MODULE := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := YourOverlay
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

include $(BUILD_RRO_PACKAGE)
```

- Make sure the APK is in the `oem.img`, did you add the package like so:

```
    PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
        YourOverlay
```

- What does the manifest look like, and what packages did you want it to apply to? For settings it might be something like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.settings.overlay.yours">
    <application android:hasCode="false"/>
    <overlay android:targetPackage="com.android.settings" android:isStatic="true" android:priority="600"/>
</manifest>
```

- Use package `android` for the frameworks itself.
- Run `adb shell dumpsys overlay` to see if it shows up there.